# GWT JSNI returning string from JSNI function

Tags: gwt, jsni

*EDIT* I think because it is an asychronous call that when I call the method data has not been set yet.

```
String theData = getData("trainer") // not set yet
```

I have the following JSNI function. The if I call this function it returns an empty string, however the console.log before it show that data is there. Seems data cannot be returned for some reason.

```
public native String getData(String trainerName)/*-{
    var self = this;
    $wnd.$.get( "http://testdastuff.dev/trainerstats", { trainer: trainerName} )
     .fail(function() {
         $wnd.console.log("error");
      })
     .done(function( data ) {
         console.log("DATA IS: " + data);
         return data;
    });

    }-*/;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought that it is a asynchronous call is correct.
The return of the callback passed to done is not returned to the original call you made.

If you used the following code, you'll get 2 messages in the console, in the first you'll get empty data, and in the second, the correct data.

```
String theData = getData("trainer");
consoleLog("The data is " + theData);
// suppose consoleLog as a native function to console.log
```

Thus you should probably do your callback like this.

```
.done(function( data ) {
     console.log("DATA IS: " + data);
     theData = data; // if theData is within the same scope and you want to store
     doSomethingWith(theData); // <-- here you can interact with theData
})
```

The doSomethingWith(theData) could even be an invocation to a Java method.